# Java code for posting pictures to fan page wall

Tags: java, facebook, jakarta-ee

1. I made a facebook application from here developers.facebook.com/apps Called "Jobs Factory Egypt"
2. I made a java application that posts pictures through the above application using my access token
3. It worked fine but it posts pictures to an album with the same name of the facebook application the album name called  "Jobs Factory Egypt" java application that post pictures to my facebook fan page, unfortunately it posts pictures.

The code is:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);

FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish(pageName + "/photos", FacebookType.class,
                BinaryAttachment.with(photoName, photoInputStream),
                Parameter.with("message", photoComment));
```

I want this code to post to my facebook fane page wall not to a specific album
so would you please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Photos posted to `/pageid/photos` (or `/userid/photos`) will be shown on the page’s (user’s) wall, but get put into an album named after the app.

If you don’t want that, then get the ID of the page’s “Wall Photos” album first (by looking at `/pageid/albums`), and then post to that specific album instead (`/albumid/photos`).

Comment: Replace `pageName` in your API call with the album id. You can look the album id up manually yourself using the Graph API Explorer. (If you want to do it programmatically, then please read the docs on how to do that.)